# Convert a gcc command to CMake for android ndk

Tags: android, c++, c, gcc, android-ndk

I need to add a c project which can be compiled with `gcc` as follows

```
gcc  -I/usr/include/epic5.1 -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/epic5.1 -I./smproject/ -o code code.c ./smproject/smlib.so -lepic5.1
```

I have moved the `code.c` files content to my Android NDK .cpp file (src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)  and also moved all files inside `smproject` directory to `src/main/cpp/smproject/` directory

Here is my CMakeList.txt content

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.
include_directories( /usr/include/epic5.1 )
include_directories( /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/epic5.1 )
include_directories( src/main/cpp )

set_target_properties( delorean PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       src/main/cpp/smlib.so
                        )
add_library( smlib STATIC IMPORTED )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log)

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, pre-built third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib}
                       smlib
                       )
```

I tried to follow [Android NDK, CMake with other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780921/android-ndk-cmake-with-other-libraries) but that didn't work for me it started throwing gradle error

tried following in `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.etpg.sampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-I/usr/include/epic5.1 -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/epic5.1 -lepic5.1 -frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Errors

```
Error:cannot find -lepic5.1
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
Warning:warning: -lepic5.1: 'linker' input unused
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> executing external native build for cmake /Users/laptop.user/AndroidStudioProjects/SampleApp/app/CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: What kind errors are you getting? Please post error messages, at least.

Comment: I have added error info

Comment: At some point you may need to tell gradle where to find the libraries (epic5.1).

Comment: how to do that in gradle

Comment: Not familiar with gradle. But check this: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-link-a-c-library-with-another-library-file-that-i-know-the-path-of/7241/6

Comment: You can create a gradle task for compiling and copying your lib's Refer: 
 https://gist.github.com/pocmo/6461138

Comment: @Mr.A `-lepic5.1` inside `cppFlags`? Maybe there are `ldFlags` and you should move there your `-lepic5.1`.

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Could not find method ldFlags()  for arguments [-lepic5.1] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions.
    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: Is  libepic in the standard loader path? you should configure that and try again.

Comment: I tried with `-L/path/to/folder` in `cppFlags`  but failed with same error

Comment: I'm able to compile with gcc and call from Java but failed to use same in Android gradle

Comment: I think you don't need an external build system, the NDK it self has some rules for this. I did this once, but don't remember how. I will check my code to see how I did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to add something to your module *build.gradle*, like this

```
ndk {
    moduleName "code"
    cFlags "-I/usr/include/epic5.1 -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/epic5.1 -lepic5.1 -frtti -fexceptions"
    ldLibs "log"
}
```

and place the source files in *main/jni*.

Perhaps, you need to change `cFlags` to `cppFlags`, but I recommend that you search for more information about this, the suggestion is based on the fact that you have `-fnoexceptions` flag, which is for c++.

You need of course `libepic5.1.so` binary to use it for compilation, if you can add it's source code it will work.